# Exchange values of $s0 and $s1 MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, exchange-server, mips

I'm using the MARS simulator and I'm having trouble exchanging/swapping the values of $s0 and $s1. If anybody could provide a solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: xor s0,s1; xor s1,s0; xor s0,s1?

Comment: I was looking at xor but couldn't figure it out at all. Could you provide an example please? It would be very beneficial

Comment: Typing `xor exchange` in google gives you [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). Do a little bit of binary arithmetic, supposing that your registers are single-bit. You should see how this works.

Comment: I think the *other* answer is the duplicate, derived from this one. In particular, OP asks here "how to exchange MIPS items". The other question asks, "how use xor".